# Two login flows with MSAL integration in iOS App

Tags: ios, azure-ad-msal, intune

We have our iOS app which has its own login mechanism and one of our customer uses SSO login (use MS account) in our app. And now they asked to integrate MS Intune in the app as they want to apple app protection policies on our app.

I've started integrated the ms Intune iOS SDK along with MSAL library as described in the documentation.

But I'm stuck with a issue which is described in the document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/app-sdk-ios#apps-that-do-not-use-adal-or-msal)

**"Apps that do not use ADAL or MSAL**

**Apps that do not sign in the user using ADAL or MSAL can still receive app protection policy from the Intune MAM service by calling the API to have the SDK handle that authentication. Apps should use this technique when they have not authenticated a user with Azure AD but still need to retrieve app protection policy to help protect data. An example is if another authentication service is being used for app sign-in, or if the app does not support signing in at all. To do this, the application can call the loginAndEnrollAccount method on the IntuneMAMEnrollmentManager instance:"**

According to it, in order for the app to receive the policies, it has to do login and enroll by calling the loginAndEnrollAccount API. But once I call this API, it takes me to MS login page where I can input email/password and if success delegate method gets called.

But my question, I end up with two login flow in my app (one by our own login and another from ms Intune), so not sure whether it is correct behavior or not.

Please let me know if you already worked on ms Intune in iOS.

Thanks.

Comment: This is the expected behaviour of you aren't using MSAL; MAM needs an Azure identity. If you haven't used MSAL (or the deprecated ADAL) then MAM requires the user to authenticate in order to obtain that identity. "By calling this method, the SDK will prompt the user for credentials if no existing token can be found. The method can be called with "nil" as the identity. In that case, the SDK will enroll with the existing managed user on the device (in the case of MDM), or prompt the user for a user name if no existing user is found."

Comment: @Paulw11: Even I tried using MSAL for authentication and I'm able to make a successful login (received access token), but how should authenticate our own server for further calls as our server API's are auth calls. Thanks

Comment: If your server cannot honour an Azure AD token for authentication then the user will need to complete two authentications. They should only need to complete the intune MAM authentication once; it is your responsibility to check if they subsequently login to your server with a different account and call `deRegisterAndUnenrollAccount` before calling `loginAndEnrollAccount` again.

Comment: @Paulw11: Okay I can ask our server if they can validate azure AD token or not. But if I do MSAL for authentication, I'm still need to call loginAndEnrollAccount API from Intune in-order for app to receive policies right?

Comment: Yes,  it because you have a MSAL token already the user won't be promoted to login again. They will need to restart the app the first time that protection policies are downloaded though.

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks I'll try and update.

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks and it works as you mentioned. I spoke with my server team and they are not sure about validation/honor the access token, but what we figure out as solution is our server can provide us a /validate API which accepts email id and access token as a params and in turn our server can call one of the Graph API from MS to check whether access token is valid or not. If valid then our server will assume that user has made successful login in mobile app (via MSAL) and can generate(and return) the own server access token in the /validate API response to app to make further calls.

Comment: @Paulw11: Do you see any issue in the solution added in the above comment. We don't want user to auth our server again.

Comment: Yes, that should probably work. It is effectively a token exchange. There is a potential for a MITM attack where an attacker could intercept that token and then replay it against your /validate endpoint and exchange it for access to your backend; how likely this is and what the impact is is something you would need to evaluate.

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks for your inputs, I will discuss further with my server team. I accept your inputs and treat them as answer for my question. Thank you again.